# Return True monkey_trouble

Tags: python

I am doing a coding exercise and I am stuck. I am trying to return True but the answer is not right.

We have two monkeys, a and b, and the parameters a_smile and b_smile indicate if each is smiling. We are in trouble if they are both smiling or if neither of them is smiling. Return `True` if we are in trouble.

I have tried to return True:

```py
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
  if monkey_trouble:
    return True
  elif monkey_trouble:
    return True
  else:
      monkey_trouble('True, False')
      return True
```

Comment: You are never comparing `a_smile` and `b_smile`, also why are you calling `monkey_trouble` recursively? Also your code has syntax errors!

Answer (score 1):

...or even more simply:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
    return a_smile == b_smile:
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
  if a_smile == b_smile:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

if you pass both parameters true or false it'll return True otherwise False

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your conditionals(those if, else and elif) are both written in a way that makes sense to you, and the python interpreter.
So because you want to compare monkey smiles and not the monkey_trouble function your conditionals should include the monkey smiles (a_smile, b_smile).
When you compare them through a ==, if they both are the same you will get True back, if you one is different from the other you will get a False, you can then just return that value to have the function return what you want. You can also write a comment to remind you of what the function does.
So:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile): # returns True when both a_smile and b_smile are the same value. False when they do not.
    return a_smile == b_smile:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your code is attempting. You need to compare `a_smile` and `b_smile`. You do this using the equality comparison operator, `==`.

```
a_smile == b_smile
```

will return `True` if they are equal, and `False` if they are not. So, a function that does what you want would be this:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
    return a_smile == b_smile:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 yes=True
    no=False
    a_smile=bool(input("is monkey a smiling? "))
    b_smile=bool(input("is monkey b smiling? "))
    if (a_smile==True and b_smile==True):
     print(True,"we are in trouble")
    if (a_smile==True and b_smile==False):
        print(False,"we are not in trouble") 
    if (a_smile==False and b_smile==False):
          print(True,"we are in trouble")
    if (a_smile==False and b_smile==True):
        print(False, "we are not in trouble")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
  if a_smile == b_smile :
    return True
  if a_smile and b_smile:
    return False
  elif a_smile and b_smile :
    return True
  else :
    return False
```

Comment: The middle two checks don't make sense and can be removed... except that would be redundant with an existing answer. So it's an existing answer with added noise.